# Does Unity UI Toolkit support CSS media queries?

Tags: css, unity-game-engine, flexbox, ui-toolkit

I would like to override the alignment for elements in my UI on small screens. I've added the following code to the style sheet, but it is not applied to my canvas in UI Builder and does not show up in the USS preview within UI Builder.

```
@media screen and (max-width:550px) {
  .section {
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
}
```

The tutorials I have found related to responsive UI are using the default Unity UI package, not UI Toolkit. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this. The images below show the problem.

---

Uses `space-around` alignment on any screen wide enough for both sections:

[image: wide screen uses space-around]

On a small screen, the sections should be aligned to the left side with `flex-start`. Instead, the container still using `space-around` with wrapping, so the sections are off-center:

[image: small screen, not properly aligned]

Any help is appreciated! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, The USS in UI toolkit is a custom implementation meant to look like (but not be compatible with) CSS and only implements a handful of [selectors](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIE-USS-Selectors.html) and [properties](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIE-USS-Properties-Reference.html).

Custom selectors and media queries are not supported

I think your best bet here is to check for the condition in a script and apply a custom Selector Class to the element if they meet your requirements

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement cfaz's answer by showing a simple example of how you might implement a media query system of your own in Unity with UIToolkit.

Add the MonoBehaviour below to a GameObject. Set the UIDocument to the one you want to be aware of screen size in the inspector. Change `UpdateBreakpoint()` to your hearts' desire. In your USS, use a selector declaration style like

```css
.my-font { font-size: 16px; }
.hi-res .my-font { font-size: 32px }
```

```cs
public class Breakpoints : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private UIDocument _uiDocument;

    private int width, height;

    void UpdateBreakpoint() {
        VisualElement root = _uiDocument.rootVisualElement;

        if (height > 640) {
            root.AddToClassList("hi-res");
            root.RemoveFromClassList("lo-res");
        } else {
            root.AddToClassList("lo-res");
            root.RemoveFromClassList("hi-res");
        }
    }

    void Start() {
        UpdateRes();
        UpdateBreakpoint();
    }

    void Update() {
        if (HasResChanged()) {
            UpdateRes();
            UpdateBreakpoint();
        }
    }

    private bool HasResChanged() {
        return (Screen.width != width) || (Screen.height != height);
    }

    private void UpdateRes() {
        width = Screen.width;
        height = Screen.height;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example! Soon after posting this question, I learned about [custom VisualElements](https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.3/Documentation/Manual/UIB-structuring-ui-custom-elements.html) and wrote similar code there rather than on a MonoBehavior. I would recommend that route since it works more "out of the box" - no worrying about gameobjects, attaching scripts, or setting references. A method like `UpdateBreakPoint()` from your example can be hooked to the [`GeometryChangedEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.3/Documentation/Manual/UIE-Layout-Events.html) provided by UI Toolkit.